# Do we have $x = (x_i)_{i \in I} \in \overline{T} \Longleftrightarrow x_i \in \overline{p_i (T)}, \forall i \in I$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $((E_i, \tau_i))_{i \in I}$ be a family of topological spaces, and let $\displaystyle E = \prod_{i \in I} E_i$ be its product space. Let $T$ be a subset of $E$, I wonder if we can conclude the following equivalence:
$$x = (x_i)_{i \in I} \in \overline{T} \Longleftrightarrow x_i \in \overline{p_i (T)}, \forall i \in I.$$
Where $\overline{T}$ denotes the closure of $T$ and $p_i$ denotes the canonique projection from $E$ to $E_i$.

I've written the following arguement:
$$\begin{array}{rl}
x = (x_i)_{i \in I} \in \overline{T} & \Longleftrightarrow \forall U \in \mathscr{V}(x) \text{ with $U$ open in $E$, } U \cap T \ne \emptyset \\
& \Longleftrightarrow \forall \displaystyle \prod_{i \in I} U_i \in \mathscr{V}(x) \text{ with $U_i$ in $E_i$, } \Big(\prod_{i \in I} U_i\Big) \cap T \ne \emptyset\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \forall U_i \in \mathscr{V}(x_i) \text{ with $U_i$ open in $E_i$, } \forall i \in I, U_i \cap p_i(T) \ne \emptyset\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x_i \in \overline{p_i (T)}, \forall i \in I.
\end{array}$$
Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to show is (very) false. The implication "$\Rightarrow $" is true and not hard to show.

But for the reverse implication,  the set
$$
T = \{(1,2), (2,1)\} \subset \Bbb {R} \times \Bbb {R}
$$
provides a counterexample,  since $(2,2)$ fulfils the second condition,  but not the first.

Comment: Thanks! I know where the problem is: if $U_1 \cap p_1(T)$ and $U_2 \cap p_2(T)$ are not empty, we cannot conclude that $(U_1 \times U_2) \cap T$ is not empty!

Comment: Just now I have noticed that your counter-example is found in a space of finite dimension. But I've just observed that it is right in the space of infinite dimension. Do you think so?

Comment: @VictorChen: Almost the same counterexample works in infinite dimensions. Just consider $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ with the set $\tilde{T} = T \times \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ with $T$ as in the finite dimensional case.